# Unexpected end of stream error on second hit to API

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, okhttp

I am trying Okhttp3 library and I am new to it. I read some of the tutorials and its working fine until this use case pops up:

I have an external Asynctask class where I am executing my POST and GET codes. So when I call the Asynctask for the first time it works fine. The second time I call the same Asynctask its giving me the error java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on okhttp3.Address.....

Can someone please explain why is this happening? I am creating the OkHttpClient object in the activity and passing it to the Asynctask.

This is the constructor:

```
public Post(JsonObject jsonParams){
this.jsonParams = jsonParams;
}
```

This is the background task:

```
Response response = null;
    try {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .build();

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonParams);
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .addHeader(APP_AUTHORIZATION_KEY, AUTHORIZATION_KEY);

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();

        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            responseBody = response.body().string();
            Log.v("POST RESPONSE", "response" + responseBody);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (response != null)
            response.close();
    }
```

I am posting my log:

```
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on okhttp3.Address@d8a95c17
12-02 10:30:11.544 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:199)
12-02 10:30:11.544 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:125)
12-02 10:30:11.544 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:775)
12-02 10:30:11.544 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:86)
12-02 10:30:11.544 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:760)
12-02 10:30:11.544 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:613)
12-02 10:30:11.544 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:244)
12-02 10:30:11.544 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201)
12-02 10:30:11.564 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
12-02 10:30:11.574 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
12-02 10:30:11.574 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at com.test.network.tasks.Post.doInBackground(Post.java:60)
12-02 10:30:11.574 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at com.test.network.tasks.Post.doInBackground(Post.java:21)
12-02 10:30:11.584 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-02 10:30:11.584 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-02 10:30:11.584 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-02 10:30:11.584 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-02 10:30:11.584 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-02 10:30:11.604 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-02 10:30:11.604 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=…
12-02 10:30:11.614 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:215)
12-02 10:30:11.614 20214-22391/com.test.network W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:184)
```

Comment: show full log help to resolve

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran I have posted my log

Comment: You do not need an AsyncTask if you use OkHttp Async requests. Use `client.newCall(request).enqueue`... See https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#asynchronous-get

Comment: Also, note: If you are using OkHttp anyways for JSON stuff, look into Retrofit

Comment: @raphPradhan try my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40925366/3629732)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .build();


   try {
         if (response.isSuccessful()) 
              responseBody = response.body().string();
       } finally {
         response.close();
       }
```

Source [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2738)

Comment: Getting the same issue. I have a post Async Task which is called everytime a post task is being executed. So I am passing your above code to this Asynctask everytime. So am I doing something wrong. It works in the first time but second time it starts creating a problem.

Comment: @raphPradhan The problem was 2 areas 1.Your Client should be in AsyncTask 2.Response stream have to close

Comment: Sorry if I sound naive. But, where do I initialize the client in the Asynctask? onPreExecute() or in the constructor?

Comment: @raphPradhan do in doInBackground

Comment: I did as you asked. Still no progress :( Have changed the code in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @raphPradhan try add header .header("Connection","close")

Comment: tried .addHeader("Connection","close") and .header("Connection","close") doesn't seem to solve the problem. :(